# Update state to render data in a form

Tags: javascript, performance, react.js, redux

I have a form which needs to display value in its input field initially. There is no post API used, only get and put. I could show the data initially by updating the state from the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. What is an efficient way to show the data in form field? Here is what I have done. The reason to put saga code is if I have done the wrong way or not. It's the flow of my code from fetching to putting the value in the form field.

container.js

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchEmailService: () => dispatch(fetchEmailService())
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  email: selectEmailService()
});

class EmailService extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    emailService: {
      api_key: "",
      domain: ""
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchEmailService();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevProps) {
    if (nextProps.email) {
      nextProps.email
        .entrySeq()
        .map(([key, value]) => {
          this.setState(state => ({
            emailService: { ...state.emailService, [key]: value }
          }));
        })
        .toArray();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { emailService, errors } = this.state;
    const { email } = this.props;
    if (email.size === 0) {
      return <div>fetching...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <TextFieldGroup
          name="api_key"
          type="text"
          value={emailService.api_key}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          error={errors.api_key}
        />
        <TextFieldGroup
          name="domain"
          type="text"
          value={emailService.domain}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EmailService);
```

reducer.js

```
function emailServiceState(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST:
      return state.set("requesting", true).set("successful", false);
    case EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return state.set("successful", true).set("emailService", fromJS(action.emailService.data));
    case EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_FAILURE:
      return state.set("error", action.error);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

selectors.js

```
export const selectEmailService = () => state =>
  state.getIn(["emailService", "emailService"]);
```

sagas.js

```
function* fetchemailService(action) {
  yield call(
    EmailApi.get(
      "api/configuration/email-service",
      emailServiceFetched,
      emailServiceFetchingError
    )
  );
}

function* emailServiceWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest(EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST, fetchemailService);
}

export default [emailServiceWatcher];
```